# Ionic Cordova InAppBrowser: Open in Appbrowser with Button on bottom which executes functions by the component

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I want to open the inAppBrowser of Cordova in my app.
In this browser I want to have a button which executes a function created in a ionic component.

My idea is to not start the browser in fullscreen (if this is possible) and start it with a height of 90% and in the 10% on bottom is a button (which is actually a button in the app)

or

I want to insert a button into the side via DOMmanipulation which starts the function in the app, but I am afraid the webside runs in it own context and can't access the App.